# How to authenticate internal corporate proxy using kerberos in order to reach external API

Tags: python, proxy, kerberos

We have a requirement to invoke an external API which would require authentication of our internal corporate proxy through kerberos.

Earlier our proxy server accepted basic authentication so building proxy using my username and password worked. But now we are asked to use kerberos authentication

Earlier our proxy server accepted basic authentication so below code worked for me.

```
Proxy = {"http": f"http://user:password@proxy_server:proxy_port,
         "https": f"https://user:password@proxy_server:proxy_port"}
```

How can we achieve this using kerberos authentication?

Comment: What API client or HTTP client are you using currently?